# mysq - Use variable (date) when SELECT * INTO OUTFILE (on file name)

Tags: mysql, csv, into-outfile

Good afternoon,

I'm using INTO OUTFILE to create a CSV file with the information of a SELECT.
I need to use variables to personalize the name of the CSV.

For example, I want to add the date NOW().

This is the idea (but its not working):

```
SET @outpath = "out/";
SET @outfile = (SELECT NOW());
SET @outextension = "_EMAIL_WithoutEmail.csv";
SET @outfull = CONCAT(@outpath,@outfile,@outextension);
SELECT *
    FROM `vn_db_tmp`
    INTO OUTFILE @outfull
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Anyonw knows if it's possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Example:

```
...

SET @`outfull` := CONCAT('out/', NOW(), '_EMAIL_WithoutEmail.csv');    
SET @`qry` := CONCAT('SELECT * 
                        INTO OUTFILE \'', @`outfull`, '\' 
                        FIELDS TERMINATED BY \';\' 
                        ENCLOSED BY \'"\' 
                        LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\' 
                      FROM `vn_db_tmp`');    
PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`qry`;
SET @`qry` := NULL;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is to use PREPARE STATEMENT

```
// You can set your VARS or use it direcly in the CONCAT
SET @outpath = "out/";
SET @outfile = (SELECT NOW());
SET @outextension = "_EMAIL_WithoutEmail.csv";

// GENERATE your QUERY with CONCAT into @SQL
SELECT CONCAT("SELECT * FROM `vn_db_tmp` INTO OUTFILE ",@outpath,@outfile,@outextension,'....') INTO @SQL;
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Remember to add `'` to the name of the file: " ... INTO OUTFILE '", @outpath, @outfile, @outextension, "' ... ".

Answer (score 0):

Just leave it there. To avoid issue with outfile you have to use 'path to file'. use backslash+' for ' special symbol.

```
SET @outfull = CONCAT('\'/path/to/file/', date_format (NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d_%H:%i:%s'), '_app.log\'');    
SET @SQL = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM some_table INTO OUTFILE ",@outfull);    
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```